# OTA update to Jelly Bean 4.3 fails (Nexus 4)

Tags: nexus-4, ota-update, 4.3-jelly-bean

I just purchased a used Nexus 4 online and it came with Android 4.2.2 (stock, as far as I can tell).  The phone does have an unlocked boot-loader and is was rooted.  I was able to un-root using supersu, but the OTA update to 4.3 still fails.  It starts to install, then it just shows a screen that says "Error" with a dead robot.

Is there anything else I might need to do in order to allow this upgrade to go through?  I don't care about keeping the unlocked bootloader or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always try flashing the 4.3 factory image if data preservation is not a problem. Grab [the image from Google](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#occamjwr66v), then follow [these instructions](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2010312)

Comment: Thanks for the useful links.  I ended up re-flashing the stock 4.22 image using that procedure.  Then the OTA update to 4.3 worked fine.